# 2 Raspberry PI connecting to same MYSQL database on the same network

Tags: linux, mysql, localhost, phpmyadmin

I am working on a project which requires 2 Raspberry Pis to share some data.

I have figured that it would be most convenient for me to use MySQL database since I had a bit of experience on that. I have installed Apache, MariaDB, and all the required tools for the MySQL database; created a copy of SD card; and I use the same tools and programs on both Raspberry Pis which means that on both Raspberry PI machines I can access separate MySQL databases using `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`.

Now, I want my main Raspberry Pi to have its database on `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` and I want to reach that database on my secondary Pi. Since I know the IP address of my main Raspberry Pi, the secondary Raspberry Pi should be able to reach that database by connecting to the PHPMyAdmin from browser as following:
`http://192.168.61.170/phpmyadmin` (192.168.61.170 is the IP of my main Raspberry PI which I want to reach on my secondary PI machine). However, I am getting "The site can't be reached" error.

After a bit of reading, I realized that I may need to change the `bind_address` in MySQL config. I have done that on my main Raspberry PI and changed it to `0.0.0.0`.

I have confirmed that with command:

`sudo netstat -tlnpu | grep mysql`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzEET.png)

However, I am still not able to reach the PHPMyAdmin page when reaching it on my secondary Raspberry Pi with the IP address. I have also read a thread somewhere which mentions some problem with the firewall blocking the 3306 port.

I have ran this command:

`firewall-cmd --get-active-zones`

And it appears that I don't even have firewall installed because the output says:

`firewall-cmd: command not found`

So that should be no problem with the firewall in my case.

Can someone advice me some other methods on how to debug/solve this issue to be able to connect to MySQL on my secondary Pi?

Keep in mind that both Raspberry PI machines are connected to same WiFi.

Secondary Raspberry PI:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8FA8.png)

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the MySQL **database** (from a MySQL client) or are you trying to connect to **PHPMyAdmin script** from the web browser? Because they are two completely different services.
The first image you linked to doesn't contain any `netstat` output, so we cannot verify if MySQL is listening on 3306 port properly. As for the second image, is any webserver running on port 80 of 192.168.61.170 that can listen to browser requests?

Comment: I am trying to reach mysql server that is hosted by main Raspberry PI. I always use phpmyadmin to connect to MYSQL so I am not sure what do you mean by saing that they are two different things,

Comment: MySQL server listens on port 3306 and accepts connections from clients following MySQL protocol (these clients may be for example PHP based, and PHPMyAdmin is one of such clients). PHPMyAdmin is a PHP script, run by a webserver - that webserver usually listens on port 80 (or 443) and accept requests from web browsers, following HTTP(S) protocol. So yes, they are different services. They only cooperate with each other. (continued in next comment)

Comment: In your case, you can have PHPMyAdmin on one host and access it (via the web) from both hosts - this PHPMyAdmin in turn accesses MySQL on it's localhost only (so bind to 0.0.0.0 in MySQL config is unneeded in this case). Or you can have two independent PHPMyAdmins on both hosts, that access MySQL on a single host - in that case bind to 0.0.0.0 is necessary. It is a difference in configuration and architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out there is nothing Raspberry Pi specific here. You just have two computers, one of which hosts a database server, to which other one wants to connect. The following is completely relevant for MySQL as well as it's clones, i.e. Percona, MariaDB (the one you likely are using).

Steps to resolve:

### I. Check if it is available by TCP/IP:

```
2nd-RPi$ telnet 192.168.61.170 3306
```

(as I understand you, this is address of computer hosting a database). Successfull connection means that MySQL service is listening, firewall doesn't blocks at all.

If you can't connect, check on the 1st RPi:

1. if it is listening, `ss -lnpt` (or `netstat -lnpt`) must display mysqld listening on TCP port `3306` on address `0.0.0.0` or `::` or `*` or local external address to which you connect, like `192.168.61.170`.

```
LISTEN   0  70     *:3306      *:*  users:(("mysqld",pid=505,fd=32))
```

2. if firewall permits connection. This is quite long topic in general, I often recommend to issue `iptables-save` and read its whole output, that's a complete firewall configuration. I feel firewall configuration isn't a primary topic for this answer, so if that's problem, better explore other questions — that topic is very well covered.

### II. Now you must have a MySQL user which is allowed access from other hosts.

In MySQL, users don't just have a name and a password; they also have a host from which connection is permitted. When you add a user, for example, with `GRANT` command, you also configure that:

```
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydatabase`.* TO 'username'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

hostname may be a percent sign `%`, which is a wildcard in MySQL, i.e. it should permit a connection from "any host".

To check if your user has ability to connect from other hosts, connect to your MySQL from where it works and check a table `mysql.user`:

```
SELECT `Host`, `User`, `Password` FROM `mysql`.`user`;
```

(those are backticks, they aren't strictly necessary in this case, but if table name or field name or database has some special symbols or conflicts with some keywords, they'll be needed, so it's a good habit to use them)

It will display all your users. Passwords are irreversely scrambled, that's normal. If there is no user record who is allowed from other host, you can create it, you can create it with a command I showed above (use `%` instead of hostname).

Additional and extended documentation can be found in the MySQL Reference Manual, section [Access Control and Account Management](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant-tables.html).

Comment: Hello.First of all, thank you very much for detailed answer. I have checked first command that you have suggested, and I am not able to connect to the IP address 192.168.61.170 on port 3306. The result is No route to host. I have already seen some threads that talk about firewall and its issue but I do not have any firewall installed so I do not understand how can it block something>

Comment: It's TCP/IP issue then. Please read just following several lines and proceed as it is described there. Also, probably there is really "no route" to that address? Are your RPis both in the same network?

Comment: I have ran netstat command and this is the result:https://ibb.co/4V12v4R . Both Raspberry PI devices are connected to the same WIFI.

Comment: Regardless of the TCP/IP issue, I see that there is nothing running on port 80 over IPv4 (there is only on IPv6). So you can't connect to PHPMyAdmin over the web using the address 192.168.61.170 until you fix this.
As for the TCP/IP issue, isn't your WiFi configured as "guest" network, ie. not allowing connections between machines in the local WiFi network but only allowing them to connect to the Internet? Many WiFi routers/APs have that feature.

Comment: Also please type `netstat -r -n` on both Raspberrys and post the result.

Comment: I am not sure whether my network is allowing connections between machines as I do not have a lot of networking experience. These are the netstat -r -n outputs from botch machines:https://ibb.co/QCNDB2p
https://ibb.co/yNyP88j

Comment: `netstat` output looks OK, so it may be your WiFi device. Try to look for setting called "guest network", "guest mode" or something similar in the control panel of your WiFi device. Try to turn it off if possible.

Comment: @raj some systems consider services running on `::` as if they also run on `0.0.0.0` and those work in IPv4. Your comment about "doesn't listen on v4" is not relevant, apache is likely available right now.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as an answer as I can't comment yet. I'm going to assume you are on a home network and can afford to temporarily disconnect your raspberrys.

`No route to host` means that your raspberry can't find the other. I see it happen the most when A) The target host is unavailable/not connected or B) the switch or router blocks the traffic. It might be a security feature of your WIFI to not allow different workstations to contact each other. If you connect your workstations via ethernet the same protection might not be configured.

A quick and very dirty way to check if your WIFI blocks the connection would be

1. To try to ping from one raspberry to the other and vice-versa
2. To try to connect both raspberrys via ethernet, set two static IPs in the same range for the raspberrys, and try to ping, then try to telnet (note that this is for testing only, as you won't be able to use the WIFI at the same time)

If either of those work, the issue probably lies with your WIFI. If not, you can try to use tcpdump to see if packets leave your client raspberry and/or reach your BDD server :

A basic tcpdump command example in your case is `tcpdump -i <connected_interface> host <other_raspberry_ip>`, with `connected_interface` your network-connected interface's name (run `ifconfig` or `ip a` to see your interfaces). You may run this command on both raspberrys then use ping or telnet and look at their outputs. You should see packets appear on both raspberrys.

*If a firewall blocks something, looking in /var/log/messages should show it.*

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this has got something to do with network settings. I have connected to some other network and it seems to work fine!

The network that I usually use does not allow connections between two seperate devices.
Pinging each other results in Destination host unreachable error.

I assume I would need to access my router settings and modify something there?

Comment: Yes, that means the issue is definitely with your router settings.

Comment: Thanks for helping me solve this problem. I should be able to solve it from there